# Google Big Query using a wildcard in middle of table name

Tags: wildcard, google-bigquery

Querying tables using a wildcard is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). From that documentation it seems like the wildcard must come at the end of the table name. Is there some way to put the wildcard elsewhere, doing something like this for instance:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `dataset.*_postfix`
```

To match every table name with a given postfix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Wildcard in the middle is **not supported**!
The closest (to example in question) you can try is as below

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as t, count(1) cnt
FROM `dataset.*`
WHERE ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_postfix')  
GROUP BY 1
```

The drawback here is that schema of query result will be determined by the most recent table in your dataset, which can be a problem. But if all tables have same schema above can work

Comment: Ok so by using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` I can perform filtering in the `WHERE` statement. It looks like this also works for filters like `_TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE "%middle%"`. I'd also guess that as long as I select columns the tables have in common, it doesn't matter if the last table has a different schema. Is that right?

Comment: sounds right - just be careful with schemas and you should be good. and yes you can use `LIKE` or any other means of evaluating _TABLE_SUFFIX to qualify to whatever criteria you need